# Making submodules visible to each other inside the same Python module

Tags: python, import, module

Say I have a folder `Awesome_stuff/my_module` that contains the following files: `my_algorithm.py`, `my_settings.py`, `my_utils.py`.
The main file `my_algorithm.py` contains the following lines:

```
# my_algorithm.py
import my_utils as mu
from my_settings import My_settings

def alg():
    # do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    alg()
```

Running `python my_algorithm.py` does not create any problem. However, things change if I want to install this module in my Python library. In order to do that I added an empty `__init__.py` file inside the `my_module` folder and outside the `my_module` folder I placed a `setup.py` file that looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'Awesome_stuff',
    version = '1.0.0',
    packages = ['my_module'],
    # # dependencies
    install_requires = ['numpy','scipy', 'numpydoc>=0.5', 'pyomo>=4.3.11388', 'mock>=1.1.3'],
    # # project metadata
    author = 'Me',
    author_email = 'me@mymail.com',
    description = 'This module contains awesome stuff',
    license = 'BSD',
    url = 'http://my_website.com',
    download_url = 'my_download_address.com'
)
```

Running `python setup.py install` generates the egg and the module is installed in my Python library. Now the main folder `Awesome_stuff` contains:

```
Awesome_stuff.egg-info
build (folder created during installation)
dist (folder created during installation)
my_module (my original folder plus __init__.py)
setup.py
```

In order to execute something equivalent to the original `python my_algorithm.py` I can now create a new Python file `test.py` that contains something like `from my_module.my_algorithm import *` and then executes `alg()`.

Unfortunately, the line `from my_module.my_algorithm import *` generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/my_module/my_algorithm.py", line 25, in <module>
ImportError: No module named my_utils
```

How can I fix this without modifying the original three module's files? I can't see what is going wrong here.

Moreover, `import my_module` does not generate any error. I'm a bit confused here.
Why importing submodules from the same folder worked when the module was a standalone folder and didn't work when it was installed in the Python library?

More general question: what is the correct/suggested way of importing/working with submodules that might depend on each other? Does the file `__init__.py` might play a role in this case?

Thanks.

OS X El Captain, Python 2.7.10

**EDIT**

As an example, I looked at the Python library [Zen](http://zen.networkdynamics.org), which is structured in a similar way:

```
Zen
    build
    zen
        folder1
        folder2
        ...
        __init__.py
        graph.pxd
        graph.pyx
        digraph.pxd
        digraph.pyx
        ...
    Makefile
    setup.py
```

In this case `digraph.pyx` (that overwrites some of the `graph.pxd` declarations) contains the line `from graph cimport *`, which of course does not cause any problem. Note that it does not say: `from zen.graph cimport *`.

**LAST EDIT**

When using `cimport` you may define `package_data` inside `setup.py` in order to set the path of the `*.pxd` files. This is why `cimport` does not need the absolute import in the example above. However, this is not possible with `*.py` files (to the best of my knowledge), and the only way is to use absolute and relative import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've added an `__init__.py` file, you've made a package. So now, you have to use that package name when importing from the package:

```
# my_algorithm.py
import my_module.my_utils as mu
from my_module.my_settings import My_settings

def alg():
    # do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    alg()
```

Comment: Yes, this would fix the problem, but it does not seem the right way to go. The namespace and the hierarchy of modules and submodules should be equivalent before and after formally creating the module. Otherwise one would have to go back and modify all the `import ...` just because he decided to create a module.

Comment: @Gioker yes, well, they are not. Sorry. Before you add `__init__` there is no proper namespace. You haven't created a module. You already had seperate modules. You combined them into a package.

Comment: @Gioker absolute imports are the recommended way to go:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, the other submodules are not in the namespace before adding `__init__.py`, but python finds them because they are in same folder. This rule should apply for a proper installed module as well. I have examples on hand where this is the case.

Comment: @Gioker If you have an example of how to achieve this, then why did you ask the question?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because I don't know why the example works but my module does not. ;-) I edited the question adding the example.

Comment: @Gioker that's a Cython project using `cimport`... I can't help your there.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know. Maybe it is a wrong assumption to consider `cimport` equivalent to `import` regarding the search path. I mean, why would `cimport` look inside the same folder for the file `graph.pxd`, while `import` wouldn't look inside the same folder to find `my_utils.py`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It appears my assumption was wrong. `cimport` behaves slightly differently because in that case you can specify the path of the `*.pxd` files inside `setup.py` via `package_data`. Absolute o relative import is the only way when dealing with Python modules. Thanks!